# vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx 64 bit error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I encountered a strange error, trying to compile my MFC project which uses VTK.

I am using VTK 6.1, in a VS2008 project, on Windows 10.

The project works fine when compiled for 32 bit, with VTK 6.1 compiled for 32 bit. When I try to compile my project for 64 bit (and also VTK for 64 bit), I get the following errors:

```
1>MainFrm.cpp
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(478) : error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>        c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(454) : while compiling class template member function 'void vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>::InsertTuples(vtkIdList *,vtkIdList *,vtkAbstractArray *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=unsigned char
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkUnsignedCharArray.h(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=unsigned char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(478) : error C2059: syntax error : '::'
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(478) : error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
1>        c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(454) : while compiling class template member function 'void vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>::InsertTuples(vtkIdList *,vtkIdList *,vtkAbstractArray *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkIntArray.h(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'vtkDataArrayTemplate<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.txx(478) : error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

Have you experienced this error? Can you tell me what is the cause of this strange error? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show the code (reduced as much as possible) which causes this error?

Comment: I would look for a `#define InsertTuples <nothing>` which would make `(` appear right after `::`.

Comment: @cppxor2arr: Anywhere I am using vtkStringArray, I get the above error (ex. CMainFrame).

Comment: @Bo Persson: I have tried this: #define InsertTuples <nothing>, and I get much more errors: 1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkAbstractArray.h(147) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkAbstractArray.h(148) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files\vtk\include\vtk-6.1\vtkDataArrayTemplate.h(102) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
... and so on ...

Comment: @flaviu2 - Maybe I wasn't all that clear, but the idea was to find some macro that matches the thing between `::` and `(`. And then *remove* that macro. We could make much better guesses if you were to show us 10-15 lines with line 478 in the middle.

Comment: I have solved: I put #undef min and #undef max in stdafx.h, and then it goes ... in case that someone will deal with the same error ... kindly thank you all.